# Why has an FMU exported as FMI1 different statistics than if exported as FMI2

Tags: modelica, dymola, fmi

Let's say I export a model in Dymola with FMI-1 standard:

```
translateModelFMU("SomeModel", false, "", "1", "me", false)
```

and then I export the same model with FMI-2 standard:

```
translateModelFMU("SomeModel", false, "", "2", "me", false)
```

I noticed that the model statistics (Sizes of nonlinear systems of equations, Initialization problem) changes.

Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 1):

The FMI standard version 2.0 has a number of additions to the FMI standard that can allow a tool to more efficiently simulate the exported model. These changes include:

- Support for Jacobian matrices
- New classification of interface variables
- Continuous state variables are explicitly listed as
  FMU variables

More information about the changes can be found in this paper from the Modelica'2012 conference: [Functional Mockup Interface 2.0: The Standard
for Tool independent Exchange of Simulation Models](https://trac.fmi-standard.org/export/700/branches/public/docs/Modelica2012/ecp12076173_BlochwitzOtter.pdf])

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I'm aware of (most) changes that FMI 2.0 introduced. Currently I'm focusing on performance of my model, as it has to be real-time capable. And as exporting it with 2.0 the non-linear system increased, my alarms went off. And what efficiency is conserned, so far, the models exported with FMI 1.0 are runing faster (by not much, but enough to notice)

Comment: My answer is to the question "Why did the model statistics change?". It sounds like your *real* question is how to get your model to run in real-time. I suggest opening a new question for that, preferably with the model code.